# FERNET_KEY configuration is missing when creating a new environment with the same DAGS

Tags: python, python-3.x, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I'm using Composer (Airflow) in Google Cloud. I want to create a new environment and take my same DAGs and Variables from the old environment into the new one.

To accomplish this I do the following:

- I check several of my variables and export them to a JSON file.
- In my new environment I import this same JSON file.
- I use `gsutil` and upload my same DAGs to the new environment

However, in the new environment, all of my DAGs are breaking, due to a `FERNET_KEY configuration is missing`. My best guess is that this is related to importing my variables that were encrypted using a separate Fernet key but I'm unsure.

Has anyone encountered this issue before? If so, how did you fix it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can reliably reproduce the issue in Composer 1.9 / Airflow 1.10.6 by performing the following actions:

1. Create a new Composer Cluster
2. Upload a DAG that references an Airflow Connection
3. Set an Environment Variable in Composer
4. Wait for `airflow-scheduler` and `airflow-worker` to restart

Aside from the `FERNET_KEY configuration is missing`, the issue manifests itself with the following Airflow error banners:

```
Broken DAG: [/home/airflow/gcs/dags/MY_DAG.py] in invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'XXX'
```

```
Broken DAG: [/home/airflow/gcs/dags/MY_DAG.py] Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

The root cause of the issue is that adding a new environment variable removes the `AIRFLOW__CORE__FERNET_KEY` environment variable from the `airflow-scheduler` and `airflow-worker` Kubernetes Deployment Spec Pod Templates:

```
 - name: AIRFLOW__CORE__FERNET_KEY
      valueFrom:
        secretKeyRef:
          key: fernet_key
          name: airflow-secrets
```

As a workaround, it's possible to apply a Kubernetes Deployment Spec Patch:

```
$ cat config/composer_airflow_scheduler_fernet_key_patch.yaml
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: airflow-scheduler
        env:
        - name: AIRFLOW__CORE__FERNET_KEY
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              key: fernet_key
              name: airflow-secrets

$ kubectl patch deployment airflow-scheduler --namespace=$AIRFLOW_ENV_GKE_NAMESPACE --patch "$(cat config/composer_airflow_scheduler_fernet_key_patch.yaml)"
```

**NOTE**: This patch must also be applied to `airflow-worker`.

Answer (score 4):

We got the same error about FERNET_KEYs. I think there is a bug in new version (composer-1.9.0). They say *'The Fernet Key is now stored in Kubernetes Secrets instead of the Config Map.'*
Even if re-enter your connections again, they are not working no.

They already fix the issue in version 1.9.1:

https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/release-notes

Comment: Combined with the additional context from @muscat, we now understand our issue. Thanks a bunch for pointing out the new storage for the fernet key. Looks like some race condition occurred and they key was never stored in kubernetes.

Comment: Thanks man! I hope they will release a new version to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

As per documentation, the [Fernet Key](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/managing/connections#fernet_key_and_secured_connections) is generated by Composer and it is intended to be unique. The `fernet key` value can be retrieved from the Composer Airflow Configuration (`Composer bucket -> airflow.cfg`). You need to check if `fernet_key` exists.

There is a known issue due to a race condition in binary rollouts that can cause a new fernet key to be set in the webserver, making previously encrypted values in the metadata database unable to be decrypted.

What you can try, is to recreate the key Composer object path in the Airflow UI under `Admin -> Variables`.

Comment: I can't believe it but you're exactly correct. Looks like some race condition occurred and the fernet key wasn't stored in the kubernetes secret key store, causing every call to get encrypted values to fail. The giveaway was that we began seeing lots of warnings for `Can't decrypt `extra` params for login FERNET_KEY configuration is missing`, which only occurs when the fernet key is not set. Thanks a bunch for the help